# Making response in Angular2 from http request staying as JSON

Tags: angular, angular-http

I am trying Angular2 with TypeScript and having issues trying to get the response from my http request.  It is an array response from the server and I have a class defined that is supposed to be mapped to it.  The code is below.  Can anyone spot the problem?

```
this.http
  .get(this.testUrl, {
    data: JSON.stringify(mockData),
    headers: this.headers
  })
  .map(response => response.json() as People[])
  .subscribe(result => this.peopleList = result);
```

People list is defined in the class as

```
peopleList: People[];
```

My People class looks like this

```
export class Flight {
  Name: string;
  Age: number;
}
```

The output is always the data in an array but just the Json array.  If I change the property of Name to DummyName it still shows the same output for the data in the array after it has been 'converted' into a People[].

Should I be seeing the class properties? I am using Chrome debugger to interrogate the variable

---

Edit adding console.log() info.  Its an array of about 300.

```
[0 … 99]
0 : Object
Name : "Simon"
Age : 45
__proto__:Object

1:Object
Name:"Luke"
Age:21
__proto__:Object
```

Comment: Could you edit your post and show us the returned data ? Simply add a `console.log(response.json());` in your `map` function. This way, we will be able to help you.

Comment: Added the log (or part of it). With a breakpoint in that map() function it only gets hit once.  Not sure if that is sign of the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The result that you get when you call `res.json()` is only a plain object (POJO), not a class instance. This means that their type is going to be `object`. The fact that u "cast it" manually doesnt change the fact that the objects arent instances of the class `People`.

You have two options to handle the POJOS:

- Define them trough an interface (for this you should change People
  into an interface)
- Map every element from you POJO array into an instance of People
  class by using the constructor method

Comment: Thanks, I assume Interface is the preferred method. Is it simple a matter of changing the class to an interface ? Based on https://www.tutorialspoint.com/typescript/typescript_interfaces.htm it looks like it